# Sending parameter in SOAP request using alamofire 4 and swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, soap, alamofire

I'm new to swift and alamofire and I'm required to work with SOAP. I'm currently using an alamofire extension for soap called alamofiresoap to send request but I am not able to send parameter in the soap request. I would like to ask if anyone knows how to send parameter to soap request? Below is the function

```
    func Sendrequest() {
     AlamofireSoap.soapRequest("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx", soapmethod: "Add", soapparameters: ["intA" : "1", "intB" : "2" ], namespace: "http://tempuri.org").responseString { response in
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.value)")
    }
  }
}
```

---

This is the output where parameter is not detected

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><AddResult>0</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

Comment: can you please provide url, parameters, HTTPmethod type?

Comment: Hello! So the url is http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx  the parameter is soapparameters: ["intA" : "1", "intB" : "2" ] and the HTTPmethod is POST. But apparently using this extension i can request and retrieve response, i only can't post request along with the parameter

Comment: Hi, New Pod version is added, which resolves this issue. can you try after updating the pod?